# get ID of created @POST instance nestJS and sequelize

Tags: typescript, postgresql, post, sequelize.js, nestjs

I am trying to create a post request in order to build an entry , I am using nestJS as backend , sequelize as ORM , postgres as DB and ts.
does someone know how to get the UUID that is created when the post request runs, as a returned value?

not really sure how to get a return of a specific value while also returning the function (because it needs to be returned in order to create the new entry